# Le subjonctif est-il toujours hypothétique?

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical

Lu aujourd'hui dans « Sally Jones — La grande aventure » :

> C'est une chance que je t'aie rencontrée.

Le chef, celui qui dit ces mots, raconte à Sally Jones qu'elle lui a sauvé la mise en un moment de sa vie où tout semblait au plus bas.

Je sais que le subjonctif n'aime pas les faits accomplis, qu'il se plaît davantage dans le mouvant, le possible, l'hypothétique et le peut-être, mais il me semble que la rencontre est tout sauf incertaine en ce cas, puisque les deux participants sont ensemble au moment de l'énonciation du message.

Cette question est peut-être un duplicata de [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/lessentiel-est-que-vous-soyez-arriv%c3%a9s-pourquoi-le-subjonctif), mais je ne parviens pas tout à fait à éclaircir ma pensée avec les réponses proposées.

Comment: Ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23036/79 Est-ce que cette réponse éclaire ta pensée?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Cette réponse et celle de Luke ci-dessous m'ont suffisamment aidé, oui. Un grand merci. Le subjonctif me semblait le choix logique, mais ce qu'il me semble n'est pas toujours en adéquation avec la norme habituelle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un seul mot, non. Bien que l'essentiel du subjonctif **soit** l'irréalité, il y en a d'autres fonctions. :)

C'est un exemple de la divergence du concept grammatical du concept sémantique. (Tout comme le genre correspond presque toujours  au sexe d'une personne, mais peut quand même être le contraire ; [la dédicace du *Petit prince*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300771h.html#ppded) contient un bon exemple où « Léon » surprend beaucoup d'étudiants ...) Je crois donc que c'est en partie la présence d'une proposition relative qui donne lieu au subjonctif.

De l'autre côté, on pourrait classer ton exemple comme usage plutôt ancien ou rare : le fait d'exprimer son *opinion*, son *jugement*. Voilà que [cet article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#Latin) (version anglaise) fait référence à quelques usages en latin qui nous intéresseraient, même dans une proposition indépendante :

> 2. **Concession**

Dans une proposition relative :

> 3. **Caractéristique**
> 4. **Résultat**

À mon sens, ces catégories (peut-être parmi d'autres) comprennent des faits présumés réels. En haut de l'article on trouve aussi une allusion au « jugement » dans d'autres langues possédant un mode qui correspond au subjonctif.

C'était donc une construction grammaticale qui chevauche une certaine gamme de significations qui sont presque mais pas entièrement homogènes. Je crois que ce n'est pas toutes ces significations qui sont disparues lors du développment du français moderne.

---

Un autre sens me vient à l'esprit, celui de la distance par abstraction, ce que je cherche à tâtons ...

Je me souviens qu'on m'a affirmé sur ce site, il y a déjà quelques mois, l'inexactitude du subjonctif dans une certaine phrase que j'avais retrouvé dans un document du gouvernment ontarien et qui ressemblait à ceci :

> C'est la première fois que le Canada **ait** reconnu ...

Mais peu de temps après, j'ai rencontré cette phrase dans [les paroles de la chanson « Salaud »](http://www.allthelyrics.com/fr/lyrics/mariemai_bouchard/salaud-lyrics-831875.html) (chanson dont on a déjà [parlé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25551/un-slow-minimal)) :

> T'es le plus beau de tous les salauds que la Terre **ait** portés.

Ces deux exemples me semblent être liés par une certaine distance du fait décrit.

Le Canada **a** reconnu, là on l'avoue ; mais « c'est la première fois qu'il **ait** reconnu » : on identifie ici un *genre* d'action, celle de reconnaître, genre défini et hypothétique, action à laquelle on décide de participer pour en produire le fait réel auquel l'indicatif conviendrait.

La Terre l'**a** porté ; il s'agit d'une personne avouée concrète, réelle, mais sélectionnée parmi *l'ensemble que propose le locuteur*, « tous les salauds que la Terre **ait** portés ». Il est proposé à l'auditeur de supposer qu'un tel ensemble ait été rassemblé.